# Connecting Pyside with Matplotlib using QtDesigner - using pushButton to draw

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyside

This is a followup question from this one. [Connecting Pyside with matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9488072/connection-of-pyside-qpushbutton-and-matplotlib/9489817)

My PythonFu is failing me to do a simple thing: design a GUI using QtDesigner, convert it, and do a QPushButton to draw something. It works when QtDesigner is not being used, but QtDesigner will be needed as the application grows more complex, so it must be used. Here is the code:

** main.py **

```
    import sys
import platform

import numpy as np
import PySide
from PySide import QtCore
from PySide.QtGui import QApplication, QMainWindow, QTextEdit,\
                         QPushButton,  QMessageBox, QWidget, QVBoxLayout





__version__ = '0.0.1'

from mpl import Ui_MainWindow

class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):


    def __init__(self, parent=None):

        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.main_frame = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.main_frame.setupUi(self)

        #self.button = QPushButton('Run')
    def plot_stuff(self):

        x = np.arange(1024)
        self.main_frame.widget.axes.plot(np.exp(-x / 256) * np.cos(2 * np.pi * x / 32), 'g')
        self.main_frame.widget.canvas.draw()




if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    frame = MainWindow()

    frame.main_frame.pushButton.clicked.connect(frame.plot_stuff)

    frame.show()
    app.exec_()
```

** matplotlibwidget.py **

```
import matplotlib

matplotlib.use('Qt4Agg')
matplotlib.rcParams['backend.qt4']='PySide'


from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas



class MatplotlibWidget(FigureCanvas):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MatplotlibWidget, self).__init__(Figure())

        self.setParent(parent)
        self.figure = Figure()
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)
        self.axes = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
```

and ** mpl.py **, converted from mpl.ui

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(640, 480)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 410, 74, 20))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.widget = MatplotlibWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 40, 471, 321))
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtGui.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 640, 17))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.pushButton.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Run", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))

from widgets.matplotlibwidget import MatplotlibWidget
```

The button connection works, but the graph is never shown.

Thanks!

Comment: did you add this line `from widgets.matplotlibwidget import MatplotlibWidget` to mpl.py?

Comment: Looks like you're adding that line to the converted .ui file.  You're not supposed to do that.  What you want to do is promote that widget within QtDesigner by right clicking on the widget and selecting `Promote to...` then select the module that you want to promote that to. This should help http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/designer-using-custom-widgets.html

Comment: @Jeff, the Designer is the one including that line automatically when I promoted the Widget in Designer, as you said. When I promote the Widget that line is included. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `main.py` module replace

```
self.main_frame.widget.canvas.draw()
```

with

```
self.main_frame.widget.draw()
```

From my understanding of `matplotlib` you were drawing the wrong canvas. According to the [docs](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/backend_qt4agg_api.html?highlight=figurecanvasqtagg#matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg.FigureCanvasQTAgg) the widget that you promoted is now your canvas and that's the one you're supposed to draw.

Comment: So now all the operations to use the canvas should be done on the widget and not on widget.canvas? Thanks

Comment: BTW, now I have to use self.main_frame.widget.plot instead of self.main_frame.widget.axes.plot?